# Is there a god mode for Deus Ex: Human Revolution?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I just finished Deus Ex: Human Revolution. It was awesome. Is there a god mode for this game?  I would love to play this game and be able to explore around without getting killed all the time but I can't find a way to turn on any "cheats".

I found something called "trainers" but they seem like Trojan horses to me.  Don't game companies enable "cheat" modes for their games anymore?

Comment: Actually not all trainers are Trojan horses, what they do is link into the game and when activating changes the values around abit so  you can become invinsible. It's basicly like hacking the game abit

Comment: OK so the Trainer at http://www.cheathappens.com/ should be OK?

Comment: Scan it first, you should be fine

Answer (score 5):

There aren't any cheat codes that I could find for Deus Ex: Human Revolution.  With some exceptions (Saints Row: The Third comes to mind), cheat codes aren't as popular these days.

With the rise of the achievement, people are more interested in playing the game legitimately to get the achievements than cheating.  The two systems don't tend to coexist well, as cheat codes would nullify the "value" of achievements.  Most games that allow you to cheat disable achievements when you do, for that reason.

The two systems do tend to have the same effect, by extending the length of the time you'd spend playing the game. Which is "better" is completely dependent on what you like, so it's not really a question we can discuss or hope to answer here.

Trainers can sometimes be a bit suspect.  They modify memory locations used by the game, which means they need pretty thorough access to your system in order to work properly.  Whether allowing that is worth the risk is a call you're going to have to make yourself, I'd say.  Since it sounds like you're on a PC, there might also be save file modification tools around, which might effectively allow you to cheat in the game.  These are a bit safer, but not totally without risk.

Comment: Too bad. I was looking forward to playing Crazy Jensen and kill everyone in Detroit and pile them up in front of the police station GTA style.

Comment: The Cheat Engine will help :)  It's safe and extremely useful.

Comment: "people are more interested in playing the game legitimately"  That's taking it a bit far, how many questions have we had about how to take advantage of Skyrim bugs to level up quickly? =)

Comment: I don't see why they can't just turn off the achievements system when a god mode cheat is used. Satisfies both achievement seekers and those who want to leisurely explore the game world without worrying about dying.

Comment: Oh it's quite possible to play Crazy Denton without cheats, especially in New Game+

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, dude. It used to be a "normal" thing for developers to put that kind of thing in their games, but now it's fallen out of fashion.

If you can find a debug menu mod that works for your version then go that route.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, try these ones: https://www.wemod.com/cheats/deus-ex-human-revolution-directors-cut

Available Cheats:
Unlimited Health, One-Hit Kills, Unlimited Ammo, No Reload, No Recoil, Super Accuracy, Unlimited Items, Unlimited Stamina, Unlimited Energy, Add 5 Praxis, Add 1K Credits, Add 1K XP, Freeze AI, Save Location, Teleport, Undo Teleport